# Get name of outlook contacts

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I want to get the names of the outlook contacts from cmd, I'm using these commands but nothing:

```
Outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m javi
```

in powershell it would be:

```
$Outlook=NEW-OBJECT –comobject Outlook.Application

$Contacts=$Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(10).items

$Contacts | Format-Table FullName,MobileTelephoneNumber,Email1Address
```

How could this be done in cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative answer: There is no CMD-callable utility that can get this information.

The only suitable tools here are PowerShell, VBA and .Net.
Among them, VBA is the most painful to use and .Net has version problems in various
Windows versions.

As you know how to use PowerShell for that, write a small script
and call it from CMD. It would be the better solution, and PowerShell is available
in all non-ancient Windows versions.